# POSTing Checkboxes with Submit button to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, checkbox

Currently, I have a piece of code which displays four checkboxes and allows a user to select the checkboxes, click submit, and the data, through the POST method, will be sent to the database (called "Spreadsheet") where it would be stored.

Typically, with a radio button, the data stored is only one element. But I noticed that with checkboxes, the elements (for my case specifically) could range from zero to four items. So my issue with my code is, only one element gets stored, even if I press all four. I think I have to store the items as an array, but how do I store + retrieve said items to and from the database?

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html> <!--  tells browser this is an HTML document -->
<head> <!-- container of all head elements --> </head>
<body> <!-- Begin the content of the document -->

<?

if (isset($_POST['formSubmit2'])){
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $accountID = $_POST['accountID']; 

mysql_query("UPDATE Spreadsheet SET category='$category' WHERE accountID='$accountID'");
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  

$values = array('0 - Luxury','1 - Brand','2 - Retailer','3 - B2B'); 

?>

<form name ="category" method ="POST" action ="" >

<?

echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'accountID' value = '" . $row['accountID'] . "' >";
 for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++){
?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="<?php echo $values[$i]; ?>" id="rbl_0" <? if($row['category'] == $i) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>
 <? echo $values[$i] ?><br>

 <? } ?>

        <input type ="Submit" name ="formSubmit2" value ="Submit" />
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, there are many things possible. What have you tried so far? What is your concrete question? What did trouble-shooting reveal?

Comment: Instead repeating hakre's comment, I'll just suggest that you change your doctype declaration to HTML5 strandards: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` (quite off-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing in name="category", set it to "$category[]".

You should be able to retrieve it from $_POST, set it to a new variable, and manipulate it how you want.

```
if (isset($_POST['formSubmit2'])){

   $submitted_category = $_POST['$category'];
   $accountID = $_POST['accountID']; 

   // rest of your code...

}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: This was the explanation I wanted to implement, thank you.

EDIT: I am getting an error where I am getting "array to string conversion in line 30" and line 30 is 

mysql_query("UPDATE Spreadsheet SET category='$submitted_category' WHERE accountID='$accountID'");
}

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Should I serialize $category like this $category = serialize($values)

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. $submitted_category in this case is an array of the categories the user selected. So you'll want to wrap a foreach loop around it to access each one. (Try print_r($submitted_category); to see the contents and how to access them)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give each `checkbox` a different name because you are overwriting their values if not.

You can also give them an array name like `category[]` resulting in something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="value 1"/> value 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="value 2"/> value 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="value 3"/> value 3<br/>
```

And then retrieve them with:

```
$categories = $_GET['category'];

foreach($categories as $category){
    echo "Selected " . $category . "<br/>";
}
```

See as well: [How do I create arrays in a HTML ?<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your array and then store it in a varchar column in your DB

Save:

```
$values = array(...);
$data = serialize($values);
// Store data in your database
```

Retrieve:

```
// $data should come from your DB
$values = unserialize($data);
// Now values holds your array
```

Comment: Hi user:

Where do I put, in my code, the serialize and unserialize? My code is on top. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For sending multiple values in HTTP POST request upon form submission you need to define HTML array.

Please refer the below code snippet

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="0"/>Luxury 
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1"/> Brand
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2"/> Retailer
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3"/> B2B
```

POST values for checkbox will be accessible through superglobal variable $_POST['category']

Here  S_POST['category'] will be accessible as an array.
e.g **$_POST['category'][0]**,
**$_POST['category'][1]**,
**$_POST['category'][2]**,
**$_POST['category'][3]**
So you need to iterate through  an array for insertion of individual values for checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. I will try to implement this right now, and get back to you.